# Issues with a route configuration that has multiple consumer endpoints on the same ftp

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

The Camel documentation says
    "The FTP consumer (with the same endpoint) does not support concurrency (the backing     FTP client is not thread safe). You can use multiple FTP consumers to poll from different endpoints. It is only a single endpoint that does not support concurrent consumers."

http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html.

Issues is with a route configuration that has multiple consumer endpoints on the same ftp server, with the same accounts, but different path:

Pseudo code:

```
<from uri="ftp:localhost/input01?username=test&password=test"/>
<from uri="ftp:localhost/input02?username=test&password=test"/>
```

In view of above mentioned limitation - does this count as two endpoints or as one ? In other words, can we expect the two consumers to be thread-safe ?

Also is this possible to consume two paths in same consumer as follow?

```
<from uri="ftp:localhost/input01,/input4?username=test&password=test"/>
<from uri="ftp:localhost/input02,/input3?username=test&password=test"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple  (1 per route) while still being thread-safe, as each use its own FTP connection (possibly with different credentials).

About you second question, `ftp:localhost/input01,/input4?...` is not an acceptable URI.
Please see the documentation, only one directory name can be provided, but it can have nested folder.

```
ftp://[username@]hostname[:port]/directoryname[?options]
```

> Where directoryname represents the underlying directory. Can contain nested folders.

If you have control on the FTP structure I would suggest to regroup the folder under a common parent in order to poll on it.

Otherwise you can use 4 consumers, one per folder (01 to 4) and  route files from 01-02 to a given route and 3-4 to another route.

Comment: for question one - if the credentials are same but the folder are from  different structures, in that case it will maintain thread safe?

Comment: As long as endpoints are different you should be fine. Otherwise camel will throw and exception saying that "Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed".